# Excel auto-number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Worksheet which contains:

*WS1*

```
ID
AlexandG
AlexandG
AlexandG
AlexandG
```

How do I go about having these cells auto-number to:

```
ID
AlexandG
AlexandG1
AlexandG2
AlexandG3
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have experience with VBA code because it can be done through a macro.

Comment: Little experience -- looking for direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick script that I wrote.  You can run this code in a module and it works relative to you selecting the first cell (AlexandG).

```
Sub ChangeNameModule()

    Dim count As Integer ' to keep track of current number to be appended to cell's value
    count = 0

    Do While Not (ActiveCell.value = None) ' stop running when the cell is empty
        If count = 0 Then
            ' do not add count to the cell
        Else:
            ActiveCell.value = "" & ActiveCell.value & count ' append count to the cell's value
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select ' selects the cell below
        count = count + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: While that does what the OP asks I would assume the data would have more IDs that don't match in which case the macro wouldn't work.  You would need to add a check to see if the name matches the one above it as well as reset the counter when it doesn't

Comment: That's definitely true. Mind you, the question just said "these cells"  so even using a loop was more modular than the question suggested.